# Arithmetic overflow error only when using UNION ALL

Tags: date, datetime, casting, substring

I get an "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime", but only when I UNION ALL the second Select Query with the first. Each of the Select Queries work fine on their own.

```
SELECT
CN.FirstName + CN.LastName + CAST(CL.DateofBirth AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [NewCustID],

/* Other Code */

UNION ALL

SELECT PPC.firstname + PPC.lastname + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(10),PPC.dateofbirth,20),1,10) AS [NewCustID],

/* Other Code */
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not (implicit) casting it back to datetime later in any other place you don't posted?

Comment: I would need some sample data from each set to make more sense of this.. But to me it seems that somewhere your date time format is flipped or rather changing format from say, British to English or vice versa. When the date value is "too large" it will throw an "Arithmetic overflow error [...]" error and is most commonly caused when SQL is under different pretenses and the month and day values swap.

Comment: a long shot here but unions try to implicit cast types from each column. Let's say you trying to match an datetime in first select with a numerical column? like it: select getdate()
union
select 9999999.99